# Calling a function before callback function

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I'm making to-do app and trying to run one function which is supposed to ran before callback function returns output. Callback fn is listening to click event and outputs user's input value to the screen. But before it happens, I want to first output h1 element on top with some text and then return callback function. How can I do this? I tried to use setInterval on the callback, but it didn't help. If user types something and clicks the add button, I want text "to-do list" appear on the most top and then after that the actual user's input itself. My code:

```
(function () {
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var userInput = document.getElementById("user_input");
function addItem() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = userInput.value;
  document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(li);
  userInput.value = "";
}

function categorize() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("todo").getElementsByTagName('li').length);
  if (document.getElementById("todo").getElementsByTagName('li').length > 0 && document.getElementById("todo").getElementsByTagName('li').length < 2) {
    var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    h1.innerHTML = "to-do";
    document.getElementById("todo").appendChild(h1);
  }
}

button[0].addEventListener("click", addItem, false);
button[0].addEventListener("click", categorize);

})();
```

[image]

Comment: can't you call the function from inside the callback before returning the result ? am i missing something ?

Comment: why not to try : button[0].addEventListener("click", function () { categorize(); addItem();});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are some questions that needs to get answers here:

- Why don't you just call `categorize()` function in the `addItem` and
  use only `addItem()` as callback.
- Why are you wrapping your whole code in an **[Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)**?
- Why are you only showing the `h1` element if there's only one element in the Todo list?

I tried to refactor your code so it makes more sense. This is a working Demo:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var userInput = document.getElementById("user_input");
var entered = false;

function addItem() {
  if(!entered){
     categorize();
  }
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = userInput.value;
  document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(li);
  userInput.value = "";
}

function categorize() {
  entered= true;
    var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    h1.id = "title";
    h1.innerHTML = "to-do";
 
 document.getElementById("todo").appendChild(h1);
}

button[0].addEventListener("click", addItem, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="user_input" />
<button>Add Item</button>
<div id="todo">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I did call `categorize()` inside `addItem` and now it's working, thanks. To answer your questions, I'm trying to figure out the logic behind how can I stop `categorize()` function from hapenning more than one time, so I wouldn't get multiple `h1` tags with `to-do` text everytime I click add button. I tho I can throw some if statements, but that's for sure makes no sense. How can I stop function executing after first time, when that function is inside callback function which gets called every time I click the button? I don't want to to be called again when I click the button second or more time

Comment: @Limpuls well there are many possible ways, you can use a Boolean flag

Comment: There are many possible ways indeed but the easiest one is to use a boolean flag, you can check my Edit.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `!entered`. Sorry, but I'm very new to javasript

Comment: `!entered` is equivalent to `entered === false`, in JS it can be shortened and it means `!true`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
button[0].addEventListener("click", function () { categorize(); addItem(); });
```

instead of this :

```
button[0].addEventListener("click", addItem, false);
button[0].addEventListener("click", categorize);
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is handling event `mousedown`that is fired before click event

```
button[0].addEventListener.on('mousedown', categorize);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made minor updates to you code below. Please try and use this instead.

```
(function () { 
    var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
     var userInput = document.getElementById("user_input");

    function categorize() { 
       console.log(document.getElementById("todo").getElementsByTagName('li').length); 
      if (document.getElementById("todo").getElementsByTagName('li').length > 0 && document.getElementById("todo").getElementsByTagName('li').length < 2) { 
      var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
      h1.innerHTML = "to-do";
      document.getElementById("todo").appendChild(h1); 
     } 
    } 

    function addItem() {
      categorize(); //since you want this to be     executed before the code in addItem()
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = userInput.value;
     document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(li); 
     userInput.value = "";
     } 

    button[0].addEventListener("click", addItem);
    })()
```